# node crypto.createDecipher wrong final block length error

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm using the following code to first encipher and then decipher.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var ws = fs.createWriteStream('message.txt');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('message.txt');

var passPhrase = 'password';

process.stdin.pipe(crypto.createCipher('aes256', passPhrase)).pipe(ws);

ws.on('finish', function() {
    rs.pipe(crypto.createDecipher("aes256", passPhrase)).pipe(process.stdout); 
});
```

I'm calling the code as:

```
echo "randomstring" | node crypt.js
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Error (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher._flush (crypto.js:177:28)
    at Decipher.<anonymous> (_stream_transform.js:130:12)
    at Decipher.g (events.js:199:16)
    at Decipher.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at prefinish (_stream_writable.js:474:12)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:482:7)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:493:3)
    at Decipher.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:459:5)
    at ReadStream.onend (_stream_readable.js:505:10)
```

I am just deciphering the output of createCipher, why am I still getting the wrong final block length error?

Contents of message.txt come out garbled on my terminal

```
kartik@kartik-lappy:~/stream-adventure$ cat message.txt 
�[��Z�*3��Kv�

kartik@kartik-lappy:~/stream-adventure$ wc -c message.txt 
16 message.txt
```

Comment: Try changing file names (Ex: message1.txt, message2.txt) instead of **message.txt** in both `ws,rs`.

Comment: @shan1024 How would changing the file names help?

Comment: Very often, issues like this happen with file operations because the buffer has not flushed and the file has not been completely written when the developer moves on to reading it back in again.  Does Javascript have a method to flush the write buffer?

Comment: I think the problem is you are reading and writing to the same file. So try changing file names like this.

`var ws = fs.createWriteStream('message1.txt');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('message2.txt');`

Comment: @WDS I've added code to ensure that data is flushed before reading from the file. Still getting the error. Here is the relevant doc which tells that `finish` event occurs when data has been flushed. [Node Event Finish](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish)

Comment: @shan1024 I'm deliberately reading and writing from the same file. If I enciphered some contents and now am trying to decipher the same, I shouldn't be getting a final block length error right?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare readStream after `message.txt` has some content:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var ws = fs.createWriteStream('message.txt');

var passPhrase = 'password';

process.stdin.pipe(crypto.createCipher('aes256', passPhrase)).pipe(ws);

ws.on('finish', function() {
    var rs = fs.createReadStream('message.txt');
    rs.pipe(crypto.createDecipher("aes256", passPhrase)).pipe(process.stdout); 
});
```